# How can I dynamically create objects of a class in Java?

Tags: java, object, dynamic

Currently I have a project that can statically create objects of a class:

```
Song song1 = new Song();
song1.setTitle("Paint it Black");
song1.setRating(4);
song1.setPrice(0.99);
Song song2 = new Song("Hey Jude",4.99);
song2.setRating(10);
```

This works just fine, but I would like to make it so that i can create objects without having to hard code each and every object into my program, because as you can imagine it can get lengthy. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Essentially, instead of

```
Song song1 = new Song();
Song song2 = new Song();
Song song3 = new Song();
Song song4 = new Song();
Song song5 = new Song();
...
Song songN = new Song();
```

Have a single algorithm to create my objects (song1, song2, song3, ... songN)  for me based on user input

Comment: Well where do you expect to get your data from? It sounds like you probably want a `List<Song>`, but you'll need a lot more clarity in your question in terms of what your'e trying to achieve.

Comment: You create the objects similar to how you're doing it here, but the details on how will largely depend on the rest of your program -- how does it interact with the user or with other code? What context?

Comment: alright i will add those details now @JonSkeet

Comment: What do you mean by *dynamically* here? Honestly for now your question looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Are you talking about an array? Have you looked into [ArrayList<>](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm)?

Comment: You need somehow to decide what values your `Song` will hold, like title, artist, and so on. So you need some source of that data. You can ask user to fill these information each time you run your code, or you could read them from some file.

Answer (score 1):

lets say u get the information from some text box.
then your code would look like this:

```
// create only once
List<Song> songs = new ArrayList<>();
//at add song button click
Song song = new Song();
song.setTitle(titleTextBox.getText());
song.setRating(ratingTextBox.getText());
song.setPrice(priceTextBox.getText());
songs.add(song);
// add the toString() method to the Song class
// print the list to see the elements of the list
System.out.println(songs);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a simple array combined with a for loop to create a size of your chosing

```
Song song[(number of songs)];
for(x=0;x<=(number of songs);x++)
{
    song[x] = new Song();
}
```

To access your song you would do

```
song[(song number)].setTitle();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you might want to have an alternate constructor inside your Song class...

```
private String name;
private int rating;
private double price;

public Song( String name, int rating, double price )
{
    setName(name);
    setRating(rating);
    setPrice(price);
}

// setters/getters
```

Seems like you're wanting something like this...

1. **Store user input using a list** – check out the docs for [java.util.Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)
2. **Use a loop to instantiate Song objects** – also storing them in a list.
3. **Use the List**

Your loop might look a little like this...

```
List<String[]> userInput = new ArrayList<>();
// Fill list with user input
List<Song> songList = new ArrayList<>();

for( String[] tokens : userInput )
{
    String name = tokens[0];
    int rating = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
    double price = Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]);

    songList.add( new Song(name, rating, price) );
}

// Do something with songList
```